# How to handle paths in R when developing in a different local location than a remote location

Tags: r

I've developed a script in RStudio and I pushed it to a remote server. The file is located within a shiny app, I do not have shiny-server set up locally and I just developed it in let's say `~/projects/app` and then I pushed it to a remote repo which is located in `/srv/shinyserver/`.

When I was developing locally in R studio, I simply set the working directory and used relative paths for accessing other files. But on the remote server, I want to run the Rscript from a cron job and the relative paths won't work. The absolute paths aren't the same on the servers so it's not as simple as just switching to absolute.

What is the best way to reference these files and continue local and remote development?

In python I have worked around this problem in the past by setting a variable to the location of the file being called:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Edit: I think the '[here](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here)' package might be what I'm looking for. If you have any other solutions please let me know

Edit 2: nevermind, `here` doesn't work from crons, which makes the path `/home/[user]` instead of `/srv/shinyserver/app` so still looking for an answer on this

Comment: `os.path.realpath()` == `normalizePath()`; `os.path.dirname()` ==  `dirname()` ; `~` in either python or R is going to be expanded to the home dir of the process owner. I'm not groking what is holding you back from using the same idiom in R that you are in python? furthermore `file.path()` can be used to safely stitch path elements together.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks for equivalencies, I'll try that out, file.path() is what I was using before here. I actually found this really interesting [thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-way-to-define-paths-for-a-file-running-on-a-cron/2061/11) by some Rstudio people and the creator of 'here' regarding this problem that I've been working my way through. One argument they make is a cron script should be taking the file paths/location as an input which I'll probably work towards in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found two main solutions to this, mainly from [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-way-to-define-paths-for-a-file-running-on-a-cron/2061/11) and also from hrbrmstr's comment:

1. Ideally you shouldn't be hard coding your paths into the script. To quote Jenny Bryan, "... an R script that functions more like a command line utility... gets called from an external place and process, e.g. cron. I think that suggests it should work more like a command line utility, e.g., expect to get paths to inputs and outputs passed to it via arguments or env vars."
2. `library(rprojroot)
   this.file.path <- dirname(thisfile())
   new.loc <- file.path(this.file.path, 'relative/path/to/other/file')`

I ended up going with this second option but will probably go with the first in the future since `thisfile()` can only be used by sourcing the script/calling it from the command line (it returns Null if you just try to run a line of it in Rstudio).

Answer (score 0):

I've in past set folder paths based on the system 'nodename'. This meant that when I ran the code locally I could use my local path, whereas when I ran it elsewhere I would use a different path, without making any code changes.

```
# Check your system information, look for nodename
print(Sys.info())

# Set location
if(Sys.info()["nodename"]=="INSERT_NODE_NAME") {
  fPath <- "/localPath"
} else {
  fPath <- "/serverPath"
}
```